# How to use composer's autoload when I already use autoload?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a `config.php` file where I use autoload for all my personal classes

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include __DIR__.'/classes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}
```

I need now to use a 3rd party class from composer which is located in
`/vendor/guzzlehttp`.

So my code is now:

```
require('Config.php'); // my config file: this is used in ALL site
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // the copmoser 
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([]); // call to the 3rd party class installed by composer
```

Which raises a 404 error : php searches GuzzleHttp in /classes

> Uncaught Error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

I have no idea on how to solve that: I need to keep my own classes in /classes

I need to autoload them because all the website uses that.

So: how can I use classes installed by composer in my website?

My composer.json content is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Autoloaders can be stacked just fine, but you'll want a check in place to see if the file exists before trying to include it.

However, if you're using Composer already, just let Composer handle the autoloading.

Add a reference to your global namespace being loaded from the classes directory in your composer.json's autoload PSR-4 section:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "classes"
    }
},
```

Comment: my composer.json contains that (and only that): {
    "require": {
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0"
    }
}

Comment: add a comma after the second to last curly brace, add this section (without the ending comma), then run `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

[`__autoload()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) is deprecated and seems to be incompatible with current best practice, [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), which is what Composer uses.

```
function myAutoload($class_name) {
    include __DIR__.'/classes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('myAutoload');
```

But you should really look at moving your dependencies into that dependency manager that you already have, Composer.

For external libs that are already in Composer, like Guzzle: https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle

For internally-developed libs: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Edit: on second look there's no reason @Devon's answer wouldn't work.